# ListView não carrega informações na tela

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, listview, maui

Estou criando um aplicativo em .Net Maui onde pego as informações no FirebaseDatabase, quando elas são apresentadas na tela, o listView não carrega essas infdormações, a tela fica em branco. Segue trechos do código.
Método para ler os dados no Firebase

```
public async Task<List<Shows>> GetShowsAsync()
{
    return (await client
      .Child("Shows")
      .OnceAsync<Shows>()).Select(item => new Shows
      {
          Titulo = item.Object.Titulo,
          Local = item.Object.Local,
          //ID = item.Object.ID
      }).ToList();
}
```

Classe Show:

```
public class Shows
{
    public string? ID {  get; set; }
    public string? Titulo { get; set; }
    public string? Descricao { get; set; }
    public string? DataShow { get; set; }
    public string? Local {  get; set; }
    public string? Latitude { get; set; }
    public string? Longitude { get; set; }
    public Image? ImageEvento { get; set; }
}
```

A ViewModel:

```
public string Titulo { get; set; }
public string Local { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Shows> ShowsCollection { get; set; }
private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var shows = await GetShowsAsync();
        ShowsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Shows>(shows);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}

public async Task<List<Shows>> GetShowsAsync()
{
    // Chame o método da classe externa aqui
    // Por exemplo:
    FirebaseDataBase _firebaseDataBase = new FirebaseDataBase();
    return await _firebaseDataBase.GetShowsAsync();
}
```

E a interface:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShowsCollection}" ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextCell Text="{Binding Titulo}" Detail="{Binding Local}" TextColor="Red" Height="200"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Como pode ver na imagem, existe dois dados com as informações de titulo e local. Porem não aparecem.
[Itens sendo identificados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x88zJ.png)

Comment: Foi definido o contexto de dados? tente adicionar this.DataContext = this; no método de carregamento da página

Comment: Mesmo assim não deu certo, nem o copilot conseguiu entender, então resolvi excluir e criar um novo projeto, daí funcionou com o código acima. De toda forma, muito obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar.